# Using json to write iframe links in Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using the **Ionic starter tabs** example app to test ionic framework. There is a json list that populates the chats page. I want specific map links sent via json, which is run on an iframe. Hardcoding a single link works (checked on devices , map displayed) but I'm unable to use a angjs variable for source.

```
<iframe width="500" height="400" ng-src="{{chats.map}}"></iframe>
```

Is something wrong with my code or how do you apply iframes in ionic the angular way?

Chat Controller

```
.controller('ChatsCtrl', function($scope, Chats) {

  $scope.chats = Chats.all();
  $scope.remove = function(chat) {
    Chats.remove(chat);
  }
})

.controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Chats) {
  $scope.chat = Chats.get($stateParams.chatId);
})
```

JSON FIle (services.js)

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('Chats', function() {
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array

  // Some fake testing data
  var chats = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'Ben Sparrow',
    lastText: 'You on your way?',
    face: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/514549811765211136/9SgAuHeY.png',
    map: 'https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zlCyVs6i4TFM.kY2_D9mPzxhg'
  }, {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Max Lynx',
    lastText: 'Hey, it\'s me',
    face: 'https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/11214?v=3&s=460',
    map: 'https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zlCyVs6i4TFM.kY2_D9mPzxhg'
  },{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Adam Bradleyson',
    lastText: 'I should buy a boat',
    face: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/479090794058379264/84TKj_qa.jpeg',
    map: 'https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zlCyVs6i4TFM.kY2_D9mPzxhg'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Perry Governor',
    lastText: 'Look at my mukluks!',
    face: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/598205061232103424/3j5HUXMY.png',
    map: 'https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zlCyVs6i4TFM.kY2_D9mPzxhg'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Mike Harrington',
    lastText: 'This is wicked good ice cream.',
    face: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/578237281384841216/R3ae1n61.png',
    map: 'https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zlCyVs6i4TFM.kY2_D9mPzxhg'
  }];

  return {
    all: function() {
      return chats;
    },
    remove: function(chat) {
      chats.splice(chats.indexOf(chat), 1);
    },
    get: function(chatId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < chats.length; i++) {
        if (chats[i].id === parseInt(chatId)) {
          return chats[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Can you pls provide your json, too?

Comment: Here added it to original question, I've used a placeholder map for all but each will contain a different one. I'm getting a blank iframe location using this with angjs variable. The rest works but only the iframe one doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

it would also be really easy to do it this way, someone clicks on a link or item or whatever you bound the click event to, when clicked fire a function that passes in the index, then have that function run a window.open(maplink, '_blank'). This will open up the map, or if you use '_system' instead of blank it will open maps.google.com links in the google maps app and if on iphones you make the link maps.apple.com in the link it will use apple maps
Example:

```
<div ng-click="seemap($index)">See Map</div>  



 $scope.seemap = function ($index) {
            if ($scope.stopdata[$index].MapLink == "http://maps.google.com/?q=0.0000000,-0.0000000") {
                $scope.showAlert();
            } else if (ionic.Platform.isIOS() === true) {
                $scope.map = $scope.stopdata[$index].MapLink.replace("http://maps.google", "http://maps.apple");
                window.open($scope.map, '_system');
            } else {
                $scope.map = $scope.stopdata[$index].MapLink;
                window.open($scope.map, '_system');
            }

        };
```

Comment: I have custom routes and locations marked onto the maps, which should ideally open inside. I'm able to do it when hardcoded in html iframe but wanted to do it via json

Comment: you can still do it via json with my method. just reassign $scope.map based on the click and pass in the index

Comment: so $scope.map = arrayofmapdata[index].maplink; and use the '_blank' to open it up neatly in the app', also make sure you have the inappbrowser cordova plugin

Comment: Can you put up a codepen/git or something, I'm sorry but I'm not able to follow up on what you are trying to explain. The ionic command for my app is $ ionic start myApp tabs

Comment: Just look at the code above, I use a ng-click on a card in a ng-repeat list. The ng-click passes in the index of the card. The seemap funciton takes that index and uses it to find the associated map link in my json. I then call a window.open function with the link, and pass in '_system' because I wanted to open the link in the native app. Or if you want to open it up in a inappbrowser you can use the '_blank' option